# Passing arguments to super class __init__ in python

Tags: python, inheritance

Consider the following class:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
```

If I wanted to define specific models, I could do something like this:

```
class FordGT(Car):
    model = "Ford GT"
    def __init__(self):
        Car.__init__(self,self.model)
```

In that way, I could create a large amount of different car models. The only problem with doing this though, is that for every car model, I am repeating the **init** function.

```
def __init__(self):
    Car.__init__(self,self.model)
```

Code repetition to me is always a sign of bad code. How could I fix this? Is it possible to pass **init** arguments to the parent without using an **init** on a child?

Comment: I used a car example just to simplify, but in fact I have a series of regular expressions, where each class defines a pattern I'm searching for. I then define all the processing functions in the parent class, so as to avoid repeating code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to drop that over-broad assumption. Repeated code is not necessarily bad code, if by repeating something you make the code as a whole clearer.

Secondly, though, I don't understand why you need the `__init__` at all, or the call to the superclass method. `self.model` is the same when accessed from a method originally defined on the subclass as it is from a method originally defined on the superclass; that is the whole point of inheritance. So you can just use that attribute throughout.

Comment: Yep, I didn't need the inits at all. Thanks!